# PyQt: syncing scroll in 2 different qlistwidgets?

Tags: python, scroll, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have 2 different QListwidgets which scrolls are synced properly with the code below. The problem is the secondary Qlistwidget (the one that is following the other´s scroll) doesn´t update its items unless i hover over it with the mouse.

I have very little experience with pyqt, so the only thing i tried is using the repaint and update methods (i added both in the code, at the end of the function). Unfortunately nothing really happens.

```
    def move_scrollbar(vs, value):
        vs.blockSignals(True)
        vs.setValue(value)
        vs.blockSignals(False)
        self.list1.repaint()
        self.list2.repaint()
        self.list1.update()
        self.list2.update()

    vs1 = self.list1.verticalScrollBar()
    vs2 = self.list2.verticalScrollBar()

    vs1.valueChanged.connect(partial(move_scrollbar, vs2))
    vs2.valueChanged.connect(partial(move_scrollbar, vs1))
```

I expect the view of the secondary or linked QListwidget update the same way to the primary (the one which i actually scroll) does.

Comment: If the two lists have equal number of items, all items have the same size *and* you're not using ScrollPerPixel scrollingMode (unless their height is **always** the same), it's enough to connect the `valueChanged` signal of a scrollbar to the other `setValue` slot and vice versa (`setValue` does not update the value if it's the current one); also, there should be no need to call for an update (and calling repaint *and* update isn't needed), *unless* you're doing something strange with those list widgets or their delegates (custom painting, maybe?).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
    self.vs1 = self.list1.verticalScrollBar()
    self.vs2 = self.list2.verticalScrollBar()

    self.vs1.valueChanged.connect(self.move_scrollbar)
    self.vs2.valueChanged.connect(self.move_scrollbar)

def move_scrollbar(self, value):
    self.vs1.setValue(value)
    self.vs2.setValue(value)
```